# Even initial distribution of space in a SplitView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I'm writing a QML app using [`SplitView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html). I want the initial space to be evenly distributed between items, but instead one item takes all the space.

[image]

```qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id:window; visible:true
    width:500; height:300
    title:'Borked Layouts'

    SplitView {
        orientation:Qt.Horizontal
        anchors.fill:parent
        Rectangle { color:'red'
            Layout.minimumWidth:50; Layout.fillWidth:true
            Layout.preferredWidth:window.width/2
        }
        SplitView {
            orientation:Qt.Vertical
            Layout.minimumWidth:50
            Layout.preferredWidth:window.width/2
            Rectangle { color:'green'
                Layout.minimumHeight:50; Layout.fillWidth:true
            }
            Rectangle { color:'blue'
                Layout.minimumHeight:50; Layout.fillWidth:true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can drag the separators between the spaces to achieve the distribution I want, and the minimum dimensions are honored. But how can I get the initial distribution to be shared between items?

[image]

Comment: Until you need to split the view in 3  or more and discover how lousy resizing is and implement your own split view from scratch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used `SplitView` before, so this was a surprise to me, but after looking through [bugreports.qt.io](http://bugreports.qt.io) for similar issues, I saw [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33689):

> SplitView is not really a layout, so we will not support all the properties found in the attached Layout property. Just set width and height directly on the items when using SplitView.

This kinda conflicts with `Layout` usage in general, so I'm not sure why it's this way, but I guess there's a good reason.

So, you can achieve it like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 300

    SplitView {
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: 'red'
            width: window.width / 2
        }
        SplitView {
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            Layout.minimumWidth: 50

            Rectangle {
                color: 'green'
                Layout.minimumHeight: 50
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: 'blue'
                Layout.minimumHeight: 50
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ! That's what I get for believing the documentation. I didn't try explicit widths or heights because the docs say: _"As the fillWidth item will automatically be resized to fit the extra space, explicit assignments to width and height will be ignored (but Layout.minimumWidth and Layout.maximumWidth will still be respected)."_

Comment: The second part of the sentence is actually referring to the `fillWidth` item, not items in general. That documentation could be clearer.

Comment: Ah...that's a different interpretation than I had, but I can see what you're saying.